# Tell browser to explicitly not post data to new url after redirect

Tags: http, firefox

I would like to do a temporary redirect (307) on a page which accepts POST data. The page it is being redirected to does not need that data to be posted to it (the POST data is already processed on the initial landing which does the redirect).

Maybe it's new in Firefox, but it prompts the user with "This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend the form data you have typed to the new location?". I would like to avoid that prompt, and explicitly state that the data does not need to be posted to the new URL.

Is there an HTTP header that would specify this?

Answer (score 2):

The right response code is 303 (See Other).

Answer (score -2):

Ah, I posted this too quickly.

The answer is to use a 302 redirect instead of a 307.

Apparently 307 keeps the request method, while 302 makes it a GET. I head just read the wiki for redirection here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection, and it wasn't terribly clear on this point. It made it seem like 302 was just replaced by 307 for temporary redirection.

Comment: There is a stackoverflow answer that addresses this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect